# Checking if its been 24 hours

Tags: java, date, time

I need to write a method that can only execute once every 24 hours. It grabs a string, called "lastCollection", then should parse it to some sort of time object. It should then get the current time, and check if it has a 24 hour difference from "lastcollection". If so, it should execute some code, and set lastCollection to a new readable time string. Whats the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Grab a pen and paper and then get coding!

Comment: Is it ok to use the system time? If so, use it.

Comment: `Calendar` is your friend. Most of the date operations are deprecated (tough it's uncertain if they'll be removed any time soon), still the `Calendar` class offers many interesting methods to work with dates. Also, to work between `String`s and `Date`s, use a single date format.

Comment: [Quartz Overview](http://quartz-scheduler.org/overview)

Comment: Does System.getTimeMillis() return a readable string though? Thats the problem. I was wondering how to use the calendar class or something of the sort to create a readable and parseable time string.

Comment: @bobacadodl if you create a new `Date` object, by default it is initialized with the current time.

Comment: You need a periodic task runner. Just google "periodic task runner".

Comment: `long time = System.currentTimeMillis();` `while (System.currentTimeMiliis() < time + (1000*60*60*24));`

Since no code shown, here is worst way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this called by something or is this something that needs to be ran once every 24 hours?

If Possible you can just sleep it. I'll need a code example to show you how to fit it in but.

**In case of once a day On a Schedule**
Get Time at start of method.
Perform Method
Get New Time
Get Difference in Start Time and Current Time
Sleep the remainder of the time until same start time of the next day.

OR

**Need to check before Performing**
Get Time at start of method save to variable
Every time this method is called check a difference in a value say Minutes(see below)
If it is greater than 24 then repeat the method

Date Diffs can be done like this:

```
Date lasttimeran = null;
Date now = null;
long diff = now.getTime() - lasttimeran.getTime();
long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
//If block to check if it has been long enough >= ensures a diff of exactly 24 hours will still trigger the method to be ran
if (diffMinutes >= 1440) {
//Do Something
}
else{
//Do Nothing
}
```

Comment: This is a method, called by something else :)

Thanks for the help

Comment: Then you will want to do a date check against the last time it was ran and the current time as I menton in example 2. You can edit your question as well. If you include code and mention the little things more people are willing to chime in. Good luck!

Comment: Alright, I think ive got this working. Thanks! Also, I'm new to this site

Comment: @bobacadodl Welcome! When asking a question it is good habit to pinpoint the problem in the question so the answers are short and sweet since this isn't a forum and youll be sticking to the site rules. You can also mark the answer as correct by the checkmark beside that persons answers. (Righ tunder the up and down vote)

Answer (score 0):

```
   Calendar expCal = Calendar.getInstance();
   while (true) {
     expCal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 24);
     Date expirationDate = expCal.getTime();
     Date currentDate = new Date();
     if (currentDate.compareTo(expirationDate) == 0)
            //Do your Work here
            expCal = Calendar.getInstance();

     }
```